# Python, TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Slight variation on FizzBuzz problem, just adding one more level.

I have read through the many answers to this Error message on SO, none of them have helped me grasp what I am missing.

So while I really appreciate the answers, what I want is to understand the WHY behind the error.

Can't this task be done using simple loop/if/elif structure, without calling a function?

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
def solution(N):
N = 0
for i in N:    
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:
        print('FizzBuzzWoof')
    elif i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
        print('FizzBuzz')
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        print('Fizz')
    else: 
        print(i)

    N = N+1

def main():
    solution(35)
main()
```

Comment: Did you mean `for i in range(ints)`?

Comment: Please post the stack trace. Python told which line had the error ... isn't that something you'd want to share?

Comment: I suggest you also rename the function parameter to something else other than ints, because when you declare ints = 0 at begining it will turn it into 0. So when you try to find i in the range ints, it won't do you any good.

Comment: does this line `ints = ints+1` have any seance? Maybe there are some logic in it

Comment: It would have sense if he didn't require a parameter in the function. Then it would be needed. If he keeps the parameter then the variable and it's +1 addition becomes redundant for this purpose.

Comment: I don't have a stack trace to post as I am not being given one by Spyder.

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
def solution(ints):
 for i in range(1, ints+1):    
     if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:
         print('FizzBuzzWoof')
     elif i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
         print('FizzBuzz')
     elif i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
         print('Fizz')
     else: 
        print(i)

def main():
    solution(35)
main()
```

put `range(0, ints+1)` if you want to start with 0 and include 35

Comment: The `0`, can be omitted. The default _start_ value is `0`. Thus, `range(stop)` provides the numbers from 0 to stop - 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate through single number. Instead, you can create an array of `ints` and iterate through it. For instance:

```
ints = [1, 2, 3]
x.append([4, 5]) #append elements you need
print (x)
#result will be 1,2,3,4,5
```

And now go with this and iterate through 1 to 5:

```
for i in ints: 
  #your logic goes in here
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `ints` is a integer, 35 the provided example. Integers are not collections, thus you cannot use the as the range of a `for-loop`. As @AndrewLi suggests in his comment, use `range(n)` to get a iterator containing the elements `0` to `n-1`.

In your code you also overwrites `ints` by 0 as the fist thing in the `solution` function, effectively disregarding the argument parsed to the function. In the code below I have added `range(arg)`, and renamed the argument to `arg` instead of `ints`.

```
def solution(arg):
  ints = 0
  for i in range(arg):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0 and i % 7 == 0:
      print('FizzBuzzWoof')
    elif i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
      print('FizzBuzz')
    elif i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
      print('Fizz')
    else:
      print(i)

    ints = ints+1

def main():
  solution(35)

main()
```

Comment: Is using 'range()' standard with for-loops of this type? Also, I was thinking that I needed to initialize the variable 'ints', ie. ints=0, and that since it comes before the for loop, it would just pass the value to the loop, the loop executes, and then ends without reseting 'ints' each time the loop iterates.

Comment: Based on your code, I assumed that you wanted to iterate through the numbers 0 - `ints`, and print _Fizz_, _FizzBuzz_, or _FizzBuzzWoof_, if the respective condition is satisfied. In your code your set `ints=0`, which means that you throw away the argument, by overwriting it by `0`. In general, _yes `range(start, end, step)` is used when you want to iterate a sequence of numbers, as it is equal to `for(i=0; i < ints; i++)`._ In my code `ints` ends up with the value `35`, which was the value of the argument. I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve by using the variable `ints` in your code.